# How do I subtract a number of years from a user-supplied year value

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a text field that will contain a given year, for example, "2011". I need to calculate the value of the year 70 years earlier.

I have this code already, which supplies a default value for the text box:

```
var LastYear = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).ToString("yyyy"); //"2011"
Yeartextbox.Text = LastYear;
```

The user is allowed to change the value of the text box to whatever year they want. I need to take the data from the text box, and calculate 70 years earlier. For example, if the text box contains "2011" I need the result of 1941; if the user enters 2000 I need the result of 1930.

Comment: What part is giving you problems? Getting the date out of the text box, or doing the date math? (hint: you're *already doing* the date math...)

Comment: I know the math, im looking for something along these lines..
   DateTime.LastYear.AddYears(-70)
I cant do the math from the date in the text box. If that makes any since. Ive been looking at this too long.

Comment: Yes, however its not always going to be last year. for instance if they want this year, its going to be 2012-70. I just have it default to last year because 90% of reports are for the last calendar year.

Comment: ok. so if your text box has "2011" in it, what *actual date* do you want the answer to be? 1941? 1/1/1941? 12/31/1941?

Comment: If someone enters 2011 it will need to read "1941"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing a year into the text box, not a date. Just, for example, 2011. That's just a number, an integer, and you can do integer math on it. (The fact that it happens to be a year is irrelevant to the `-` operator.)

If you want to subtract 70 years from that, just do 2011 - 70:

```
var year = Int32.Parse(Yeartextbox.Text) - 70;
```

Comment: You are exactly right! Wow im impressed and overwhelmed at home many people respond so fast and are very helpful!

Comment: I do and I will! as soon as i figure out what one does what im looking for. Im sure a few will do what i need.

Comment: I think this was the fastest one liner solution. (for my need)

Answer (score 1):

What is stopping from you to read from the Textbox and Assign to a `DateTime` object and call the `AddYears` function ?

```
DateTime dateEntered=DateTime.Parse(Yeartextbox.Text);
var thatYear= dateEntered.AddYears(-70);
Yeartextbox.Text = thatYear.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: the textbox doesn't have a date in it, otherwise, definitely this.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: the question says so **I'm having trouble taking the data from the text box and subtracting 70 years form that**

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: Yes. **subtract 70 years from a date in a textbox** is not a valid title then.

Comment: @Shyju DateTime cannot parse 4-digit number, such as 2011. An exception will be thrown.

Comment: As soon as I figure out what the OP is trying to ask I will edit the question to be clearer; right now there's more than one way to interpret his question.

Comment: ahh your right, it should be subtract 70 years from an int in a text box! my apologies

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand....but is this what you're looking for....pre-poluting the text box with -70?

```
var LastYear = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-70).ToString("yyyy"); //"2011" 
Yeartextbox.Text = LastYear;
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-70).ToString("yyyy") == "2011"`?? I hope not.

Comment: in 60 more years this answer will be correct! Reverse bit rot?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two text boxes, here's how to do it:

```
// Get year as an integer from the text box
int currentYearAsInt = int.Parse(txtCurrentYear.Text);

// Create DateTime out of it (January 1st 1984, for example)
DateTime currentYear = new DateTime(currentYearAsInt, 1, 1);

// Create new DateTime 70 years older (remember, you cannot just call AddYears on the object, you have to assign returned value)
DateTime oldYear = currentYear.AddYears(-70);

// Populate new text box with old year's value (or do whatever you want with it
txtOldYear.Text = oldYear.Year.ToString();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> For instance if they want this year, its going to be 2012-70

If i understand you correctly, you have problems to translate the year from the user to a `DateTime` object.

So if the user entered f.e `2005` you want `1935-01-01`. Am i right?

This would work:

```
var input = "2005";  // Yeartextbox.Text
int year = 0;
DateTime result;
if(int.TryParse(input, out year))
{
    result = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddYears(-70); //1935-01-01
}
```

Comment: Tim, you are correct. This is a great solution if your actually using a date. I was using the text box just to hold the year(yyyy) making it an int, and then subtracting 70.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string initialYear = "2011";
        int year;
        string calculatedYear;

        if (int.TryParse(initialYear, out year))
        {
            var initialDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
            calculatedYear = initialDate.AddYears(-70).Year.ToString();
        }
        else
        { 

            // Handle error since no valid value was entered
        }
```

This will do the work (you obviously need to adapt it to your code). If it doesn't you might need to assure that the screen is correctly refreshed.